# Wordpress API not updating a post - using Python

Tags: python, wordpress, rest

I am creating posts on my site with the Wordpress API, using Python.

Everything works well.

When I am trying to update a post, it doesn't update.

I have no idea if the problem is in my code, or maybe a setting I should change?

In this example I am trying to change a simple setting on a post with just a title. Nothing fancy.

```
import requests
import json
import base64

credentials = "username:password"
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
post_url = "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

header = {"Authorization": "Basic " + token.decode('utf-8'), "Content-Type":"application/json"}

postID = "1122"

data_to_send = {"comment_status": "closed"}

json_to_send = json.dumps(data_to_send)

response = requests.post(post_url + "/" + postID , headers=header, json=json_to_send)
```

Here is the response. The "modified" time is correct (and is also reflected in the site admin) but the value of comment_status has not changed.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "id": 1122,
    "date": "2022-02-03T21:24:32",
    "date_gmt": "2022-02-03T19:24:32",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/?p=1122"
    },
    "modified": "2022-02-03T21:24:32",
    "modified_gmt": "2022-02-03T19:24:32",
    "slug": "",
    "status": "draft",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/?p=1122",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "title"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "",
        "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "",
        "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [1],
    "tags": [],
    "acf": {
        "Description": "",
        "first_page_image_id": "",
        "Date": "",
        "Authors": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Filename": "",
        "Format": "",
        "Donated_by": "",
        "ocr": "",
        "Series": ""
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/posts\\/1122"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [{
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [{
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/types\\/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [{
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/users\\/1"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [{
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/comments?post=1122"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [{
                "count": 1,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/posts\\/1122\\/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "predecessor-version": [{
                "id": 1123,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/posts\\/1122\\/revisions\\/1123"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [{
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/media?parent=1122"
            }
        ],
        "wp:term": [{
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/categories?post=1122"
            }, {
                "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/wp-json\\/wp\\/v2\\/tags?post=1122"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [{
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https:\\/\\/api.w.org\\/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helps. Time to turn off plugins as one does in Wordpress.